# HQL subqueries in hibernate

Tags: hql

I have to write hql for one of the subquery. I am getting querysyntax exception.

Below is my code.

```
public List<URPTempSensor> findTempSensorObjs(String systemId, Character isLatest) {

    Map<String,Object> params = new HashMap<String,Object>();
    List<URPTempSensor> tSensorList = new ArrayList<URPTempSensor>();
    params.put("systemId", systemId);
    params.put("status", isLatest);
        String sql = 
            "select * from " + 
                "(select tsensor.time, tsensor.tId from URPTempSensor tsensor where " +
                "tsensor.isLatest=\'"+isLatest+"\' and tsensor.urpTempSystemId.systemId=\'"+systemId+"\' order by time desc)where rownum<=3";
    tSensorList = this.urpTempDao.find(sql,params);
    return tSensorList;
}
```

can anyone help on this

Answer (score 0):

Probably you are receiving a syntax error because the HQL not support a `SELECT` after a the `FROM` clause:

```
"select * from " + 
            "(select
```

You need to rethink your SQL to write it on HQL.